# App Inventor: How to cache a webpage locally in app?

Tags: app-inventor

How to cache a webpage locally on an Android phone with app made by **App Inventor**? I'm actually making a web browser app for Android and I want it load my website without internet! Please help!!!

Comment: this questions lacks a lot of details, especially code that you tried...

Comment: you can't cache webpages using App Inventor. The only thing you can do is to store the complete webpage in the assets of your app, [see this example](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2htmlread)

Answer (score 1):

Dowload the HTML content of the page and then display it .

```
  WebView mWebView = null;
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("yourhtmlfilepath");
```

dont forget to add file:/// before path

Comment: the question was about App Inventor, which means, your answer unfortunately will not help here...